# Syntax error with database search

Tags: python, web2py

I'm creating a product review website through web2py and have encountered difficulty whilst adding a search feature. Here's the code I have so far:

```
def index():
rows = db(db.reviews).select()

name_default = request.vars.name
body_default = request.vars.body
objects_default = request.vars.objects

form = SQLFORM.factory(
            Field("Item Name", default = name_default),
            Field("Body", default = body_default),
            Field("Objects", default = objects_default),
            formstyle = 'divs'
            submit_button = "Search"
            )

query = db.db1.id_user == auth.user_id

if form.process().accepted:
    name = form.vars.name
    body = form.vars.body
    objects = form.vars.objects

count = db(query).count()
results = db(query).select(orderby=~db.db1.data)
msg = T("%s registers" % count)
return dict(form=form, msg=msg, results=results)

return locals()
```

The error I'm getting is a syntax error on line 23 character 28 (the `submit_button = "Search"` line).

Comment: Which line is line 23?

Comment: submit_button = "Search"

Comment: @Rob Ignore this, I've worked it out; thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was a typographical error. Missing comma on line 23.